# Accidental wars

Tags: war

I'm curious to know if there have been any armed conflicts that are generally regarded as full blown wars (i.e. not border skirmishes) which were *started accidentally*. By accidentally, I mean something along the lines of some person(s):

1. Killing someone by mistake (e.g. an important person of one party)
2. Unknowingly crossing borders that should not have been crossed
3. Misspeaking in an important official gathering (e.g. offending another party)

or things along similar lines.

Comment: Perhaps this question is worded poorly or mis-tagged; please do not hesitate to edit or ask for clarification!

Comment: The idea of a "declaration of war" is a really modern concept that covers only a very small portion of the history of warfare. Furthermore, it is a uniquely western concept. So the answer to your question is likely no but only because of your definitions

Comment: @StuartAllan Do you have any idea how I might re-word it to make the concept more applicable to non-western societies? Perhaps *conflict*? That seems to broad. I'm having trouble narrowing it beyond that - *war* was the most applicable term I could think of, but I suppose that it doesn't suffice. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @StuartAllan what are you talking about? [Declarations of war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_of_war#History) may have looked very different over history, but they are much older than modern times and are not uniquely Western.

Comment: The problem with this question is that typically, those types of events are **used** as excuses to start wars. Wars are only an extension of politics; there are plenty of cases where one started "accidentally" in that one side miscalculated, but in general one side (or a faction therein) **wanted** the war.

Comment: @Semaphore presumably differentiating which were *actually accidental* would be subjective? I thought I had a pretty good question, but if the entire premise is subjective then I suppose it should be closed or deleted.

Comment: You should look for the assassination of Franz Ferdinand, which triggered the Great War. It is pretty close to accidental, considering they avoided the terrorist squad, and then met another terrorist just by unlucky as he was lost.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Yeah, it seems rather subjective to me. For instance in Bregalad's example I'd say it wasn't accidental at all since the Austro-Hungarian government deliberately used the assassination as an excuse to attack Serbia. Obviously this hinges on subjective interpretations of "accidental war" really means. If you could define this, then it might be objectively answerable, though you'd have to be careful about not making it too broad.

Comment: I think it would have to be a more modern thing. Can you have an accidental war when it takes months for you to gather your soldiers from across the country side? If we look at the Cold War I can see several examples of war almost being set off by accident, if we take accident to include misunderstandings and such. One example being Vasili Arkhipov being the sole 'No' vote for a Soviet submarine to launch a nuclear device during the Cuban missile crisis. I think an accidental war would require the speed of modern decision making and modern response times to occur.

Comment: @Bregalad - I thought about that one, but IMHO it wouldn't qualify because the assassination was quite deliberate. You could even argue it worked too, as the country the assassin wanted was indeed formed at the end of the ensuing war.

Comment: @PeskyToaster I was actually talking about some *accidental thing that happened* that caused two parties to war against one another. This doesn't mean one party gathering troops at the border, then a soldier from the other party wandering into their territory resulting in their death thus causing a battle. I mean some incident that caused a war unintentionally, without any predetermined notion of *wanting* to go to war. So intentional assassinations to start a war would not count, for example, but accidental death of a politician in another territory that started an armed conflict *would*.

Comment: @T.E.D. but did the assassins really want to initiate a European wide war? The incident might have been intentional, but not the consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spanish-American war was almost certainly started by an accident. The Casus Belli was an explosion that sank the [USS Maine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Maine_(ACR-1)#Investigations) in Havana Harbor. There's a good chance it wasn't even an external source that caused the explosion. Even if it was a mine, it is highly unlikely the mine was placed where it was in hopes of sinking a US ship. Even one of the newspaper magnates who was hyping it up in his papers publicly admitted this at the time.

However, US public opinion was strongly in favor of Cuban independence (from Europe, that is), and it didn't take much to get it thinking this was a stellar pretense to use war to force the issue. So was the start of the war itself an accident? Not really. But it was almost certainly started by one.